# Php Class 'DateInterval' not found

Tags: php, dateinterval

I am using php version 5.4.24 and I can't use the class DateInterval.
I get this error: **PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DateInterval' not found**

```
$interval       = new DateInterval('P91D');
```

What should I do in order to make this code work?

Answer (score 16):

You need to add the following class in the Controllers. Also make sure your php version **(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)**

```
use DateTime;
use DatePeriod;
use DateInterval;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

}
```